# How to check if a float is positive denormalized/negative denormalized or not denormalized

Tags: c, floating-point, normalization, denormal-numbers

How to check if a float is positive denormalized/negative denormalized or not denormalized.

I tried to do:

```
int is_denorm(float f)
{
  unsigned int x = *(int*)&f; 
  unsigned expMask = (1 << 8) - 1;
  expMask = expMask << 23;
  //now needs to check if the exp is all zero how can I do it
}
```

Comment: How about [fpclassify](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fpclassify)?

Answer (score 3):

> check if a float is positive denormalized/negative denormalized or not denormalized

Note that both C and [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) use *subnormal* and not *denormal*.

```
#include <math.h>

//  1 +subnormal
// -1 -subnormal
//  0 not subnormal
int subnormalness(float x) {
  if (fpclassify(x) == FP_SUBNORMAL) {
    return signbit(x) ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Avoid code like `*(int*)&f;` and `expMask << 23, ...`.  That runs into aliasing concerns, `float` encoding issues and size of `unsigned`.

---

Sometimes 0.0 is desired to be classified like *sub-normals*

```
int subnormalzeroness(float x) {
  switch (fpclassify(x))
    case FP_SUBNORMAL: // fall through
    case FP_ZERO:
      return signbit(x) ? -1 : 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Code such as below works well too when NANs behave per *IEEE-754* and fails `<` comparisons, otherwise append a `&& !isnan(x)` to the `return`.

```
int subnormalzeroness_alt(float x) {
  return fabsf(x) < FLT_MIN;  
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not as efficient, but more fun: `return copysign(fpclassify(x) == FP_SUBNORMAL, x);`.

Comment: Or `return x < 0 ? -(-FP_MIN < x) : x == 0 ? 0 : x < FP_MIN;`.

Comment: `copysign()` --> Nice.  Of course we now get 4 potential results including -0.0.

Comment: Naw, the `copysign` result is converted to the `int` return type. So the return values are just −1, 0, and +1. Unless you are in a sign-and-magnitude C implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, so the return type brings it back to 3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Aside,  IIRC,  IEEE-754 classifies 0.0f as a _normal_ and C has `isnormal(0.0f)` as false.  Is that your understanding too?

Comment: Yes, IEEE 754-2019 2.1 says “In this standard, zero is neither normal nor subnormal.” The bits in its representation are consistent with the subnormal format (its significand interpreted like any subnormal number has value zero), so the only reason to not consider it subnormal may be for easier writing in various places where zero is important or some sort of underflow effect does not apply or such.

Comment: Although the question refers to “denormalized,” not subnormal. Subnormal numbers are those (non-zero) numbers lower in magnitude than the normal numbers. “Denormalized” is not used in the IEEE 754 standard but could refer to representations where the significand is less than a normal or canonical significand. In IEEE-754 binary format, the only such representations are for zero and the subnormals. In decimal formats, numbers may have multiple representations, so some of them could be called denormalized. And, since it is not standard, you could call zero denormalized. OP would have to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making assumptions about the representation of `float` and `unsigned int`, including size and endianness and encoding, you should use the `fpclassify` macro defined in `<math.h>` specifically designed for this purpose:

```
int is_denorm(float f) {
    return fpclassify(f) == FP_SUBNORMAL;
}
```

Depending on its argument, `fpclassify(x)` evaluates to one of the *number classification macros*:

```
FP_INFINITE
FP_NAN
FP_NORMAL
FP_SUBNORMAL
FP_ZERO
```

They represent the mutually exclusive kinds of floating-point values. They expand to integer constant expressions with distinct values. Additional implementation-defined floating-point classifications, with macro definitions beginning with `FP_` and an uppercase letter, may also be specified by the implementation.

The `signbit` macro can be used to extract the sign of a floating point value (of type `float`, `double` or `long double`).  Note that `signbit(x)` evaluates to non zero for negative values and non-values, including `-0.0` for which `x < 0` would evaluate to false.

Note that your approach has some problems even on architectures using IEEE 754 single precision `floats` and 32-bit integers with the same endianness:

- to avoid aliasing issues, instead of `unsigned int x = *(int *)&f;` you should write `uint32_t x; memcpy(&x, &f, sizeof x);`
- testing the exponent bits is not sufficient to detect subnormal values as the values `0.0` and `-0.0` also have all exponent bits set to 0.

Also note that *denormalized* is not always the same as [*subnormal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number): In the IEEE 754 standard, *subnormal* refers to non zero numbers smaller in magnitude than normal numbers with an implicit `1` mantissa (*denormal* is not used anymore in the IEEE 754 standard nor in the C Standard). Other floating point standards with multiple representations may have *denormalized* numbers for other sets of values.

Comment: @chqrlie: FYI, `fpclassify` does not “return.” It cannot be a function in C because any `float`, `double` or `long double` argument would have to be converted to the parameter type, and then the function would not know the original type and would not be able to distinguish subnormal `float` arguments from some normal `double` arguments. The C standard refers to it as a macro. So it will just evaluate to a value, not return a value. It could be implemented with `_Generic`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: sharp eyes as always :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: correct! answer updated.